# Is it best to UVW unwrap before or AFTER applying a 'bend' modifier?

Tags: modifiers

So I'm creating modular pieces and then bending them into a curve to make a corridor. With 3DS Max I could simply tell it to preserve the UV's but I'm not sure if Blender will do that or deform them once the 'Bend' modifier has been applied to it.

I intend to make one modular piece, copy it a few times and then bend it into a slight arc but I'm just not sure if I should UVW unwrap the modular piece before or after using this modifier. It would be kinda pointless to create modular pieces if I need to unwrap each part after applying this modifier.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). You can happily unwrap it first. Blender doesn't alter UV maps when applying deform modifiers.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your reply! I'd hate to have to unwrap every single modular piece each time xD

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :).